# How can I get info about a vehicle be or not actived in simmulation?

Tags: veins

I want to know if a vehicle is still active in simulation. If I want to set some task to some vehicles, I want to choose those who are not going to be offline early. Is there some method `isActive()` to check the activity of vehicles in veins?

Answer (score 0):

TraCIScenarioManager manages only active vehicles. It has a method [`getManagedHosts`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.h#L102) for getting a list of all active (managed) vehicles.